# How to get version to be uninstalled inside rpm scriptlet?

Tags: rpm

I have the following scenario:

1. I install version 1 of a package, it does custom operations during post install (copying some files to a location)
2. I install version 2 of the same package
3. I want to uninstall version 1. To be able to do the cleanup I'll need to know the exact version during the post uninstall, to clean up the files that were copied.

Is there a way to get the version number in a rpm scriptlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` scripts are called from the relevant version of the `rpm` file.  So if you upgrade from version 1.0 to 1.1 then the pre/post install scripts are run from the 1.1 version of the rpm and the pre/post uninstall scripts are run from the 1.0 version.

This makes it quite easy for the scripts to handle their own version properly.

For example, here's an extract from a SPEC file

```
%pre
echo Pre called with version %{version}-%{release}

%post
echo Post called with version %{version}-%{release}

%preun
echo Pre-un called with version %{version}-%{release}

%postun
echo Post-un called with version %{version}-%{release}
```

They are very simple, just to demonstrate this.  When you build the rpm then these values are embedded into the rpm

eg

```
% rpm -q --scripts -p sweh-test-1.0-0.x86_64.rpm 
preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
echo Pre called with version 1.0-0
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
echo Post called with version 1.0-0
preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
echo Pre-un called with version 1.0-0
postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
echo Post-un called with version 1.0-0
```

Now let's install version 1.0.0 of this package:

```
% sudo rpm -i sweh-test-1.0-0.x86_64.rpm 
Pre called with version 1.0-0
Post called with version 1.0-0
```

So far, pretty expected.  The pre/post install scripts are run.

Now let's upgrade to version 1.1:

```
% sudo rpm -U sweh-test-1.1-0.x86_64.rpm
Pre called with version 1.1-0
Post called with version 1.1-0
Pre-un called with version 1.0-0
Post-un called with version 1.0-0
```

Note the order of the calls and the version numbers; pre/post install are called and the version-release matches the new version, and then pre/post uninstall are called with the old version number.

So the idea is that you don't need to *derive* this information, you can include it directly in the rpm spec file via use of the `%` macros.

Comment: for a complete list on the order of the scriptlets: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  The rpm database is locked while your install is progressing.  The easy way would be to provide that information as a text-file in the rpm which you are maintaining.